# error in element existing identification when using 'if in'

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, pandas-groupby

Here is my code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,1,2,3,3],'b':[1,2,3,1,2,3,3],'type':[1,0,1,0,1,0,1]})
def add_buy_label(group):
    behavior_type = group.type.astype(int)
    if 1 in group['type']:
        group['buy_label'] = 1
    else:
        group['buy_label'] = 0

    return group[['a', 'b', 'type','buy_label']]
```

The functions above is to make the buy_label to 1 for all the a-b item as long as one (type = 1) in the group exist, however, the result after

```
df1.groupby(['a','b'],as_index = False).apply(add_buy_label)
```

is

```
    a  b  type  buy_label
0  1  1     1          0
1  2  2     0          1
2  3  3     1          0
3  1  1     0          0
4  2  2     1          1
5  3  3     0          0
6  3  3     1          0
```

It is pretty obvious that the row with 3 is wrong, because there is type = 1 existing in the group of (a=3,b=3), but the according buy_label is 0.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem `in` test index values, not columns values.

```
#sorting for better seen groups 
df1 = df1.sort_values(['a','b'])
df2 = df1.groupby(['a','b'],as_index = False).apply(add_buy_label)
print (df2)
   a  b  type  buy_label
0  1  1     1          0
3  1  1     0          0
1  2  2     0          1 <- return 1 only because index == 1 per group (2,2)
4  2  2     1          1
2  3  3     1          0
5  3  3     0          0
6  3  3     1          0
```

So need comapre by `1` with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for check at least one `True`:

```
if group['type'].eq(1).any():
#what is same as
if (group['type'] == 1).any():
```

Comment: Hi dear friend, why `if 1 in group['type'] ` would indicate the dataframe index instead of column value ? I don't understand...

Comment: @exteralvictor - It is gotcha, check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator)

Answer (score 1):

As explained, `in` with a series checks for membership in series index rather than series values. Think of a series like a Python `dict` and you'll see how the treatment is consistent: `for k in my_dict` checks for membership in dictionary keys.

An alternative way to formulate your logic is to use `groupby` + `transform` with `unique`:

```
df1['buy_label'] = df1.groupby(['a', 'b'])['type']\
                      .transform('unique')\
                      .apply(lambda x: 1 in x)\
                      .astype(int)
```